# Arcpy Script using Spatial Join is going slower than it should

Tags: python, performance, gis, geospatial, arcpy

I have a complicated script with multiple functions that I have gotten running pretty quick (in total it went from taking 10 minutes to 4 minutes).  However, I am having issues with the spatial join taking longer than I believe it should.  Whenever I use feature layers in the spatial join it takes 12-13 minutes just for the spatial join step of the script.  So I tried creating files from the layers prior (using CopyFeatures) and the spatial join will run in about 1.5 minutes but it adds on about another minute for running 2 copy features.  I have pasted in the part of the code where this occurs (the field mapping takes a split second so it is not that, it is definitely the spatial join that is hanging after using print statements to figure it out).  My question, is first off, do I have something messed up that is causing the hang of time?  Second, is there a better method to get things running faster using something other than a spatial join that will accomplish the same thing?  I looked into the use of cursors but am not sure it is possible to do what I want.  Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks.

```
IfExists(TargetFile)
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(HexLyr, TargetFile)
IfExists(JoinFile)
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(PtLyr, JoinFile)
fieldmappings = arcpy.FieldMappings()
fieldmappings.addTable(TargetFile)
fieldmappings.addTable(JoinFile)
FinalNormIndex = fieldmappings.findFieldMapIndex("Final")
fieldmap = fieldmappings.getFieldMap(FinalNormIndex)
field = fieldmap.outputField
fieldmap.outputField = field
fieldmap.mergeRule = "mean"
fieldmappings.replaceFieldMap(FinalNormIndex, fieldmap)
NullPctIndex = fieldmappings.findFieldMapIndex("NullPct")
fieldmap = fieldmappings.getFieldMap(NullPctIndex)
field = fieldmap.outputField
fieldmap.outputField = field
fieldmap.mergeRule = "sum"
fieldmappings.replaceFieldMap(NullPctIndex, fieldmap)
IfExists(SpatialJoinFile)
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(TargetFile, JoinFile, SpatialJoinFile, field_mapping = fieldmappings, match_option = "CLOSEST", distance_field_name = "Dist")
```

Comment: Do you have a spatial index on the target and join file? How many rows are in each? What happens if you reduce the value of the distance field?

Comment: I did not set up any spatial index on the target or join file.  Would that help speed things up? If so, how do you accomplish that?

Comment: I'm not an ESRI user, so I can't help you with the how. But, yes, in general spatial joins speeds are vastly increased by the use of an index. I am more of a Postgres/Postgis person and from experience you can get orders of magnitude improvements though this depends on many things, like geometry complexity, number of geometries, geometry operation, etc, so I would say it is worth a go.